# ExtJS - Disable Combobox onWidgetAttach not working

Tags: extjs6.2

I am displaying a combobox in a grid. The value for combobox comes from a local store. The combobox needs to be disabled for one of the rows. I used widget.setDisabled(true). It seems to work but when i click, the combo box is showing me all the values.

Below is my code:

```
{
xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
text: 'Code',
dataIndex: 'code',
widget: {
    xtype: 'codecombo'
},
editor: {
    xtype: 'codecombo'
},
onWidgetAttach: function (col, widget, rec) 
{
    widget.setDisabled(rec.get('type') === 2);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you're not really trying to disable the combobox, but rather disable editing altogether?

Comment: I was wrong with the solution. It did disable the editing all together :( ..Will edit the question.. I am now reseaching on isCellEditable. Any pointers would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you explain why are your using `editor` and `widget` config together ?

Comment: If i don't have an editor in place, the renderer is not getting triggered for other columns which needs to change its value depending upon the widget column